# Importing a RAML file with custom types into Paw does not set JSON bodies correctly

Tags: paw-app

I have a RAML 1.0 type definition:

```
types:
  uuid: string
  url: string
  html: string
  Credentials:
    description: Authentication credentials for a user
    type: object
    properties:
      userName: string
      password: string
```

With an endpoint definition that takes the object as a POST JSON body:

```
/login:
  is: [mobile]
  displayName: Authentication
  post:
    description: Login
    body:
      application/json:
        type: Credentials
```

If I import it into Paw, my endpoints are shown, but the custom type's fields are not correctly shown as a JSON object; instead, a "JSF" label is shown which then shows a popup which seems to indicate that the schema is not correctly referenced:

[image: Paw app]

Should this work in the current version of Paw (3.1.3) with RAML 1.0? Are there changes to my RAML file I can make that will allow it to be imported correctly?

Thanks!